# Amazon S3 URL redirect with trailing forward slash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to do some URL redirects and the redirects are working properly, however if I try to redirect a URL that ends in a forward slash the redirect does not work. For example, I'd like to redirect `http://mydomain/foo/` to `/bar/` does not work. However `http://mydomain/foo` to `/bar/` does redirect properly. Can anyone tell me how to redirect urls with training forward slashes properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if a web server indicates a trailing slash, it immediately looks for the default file (e.g. index.html) in the given directory.
This convention is speeding up the web server work.

e.g.

```
http://mysite/test/ ==> is a directory
http://mystite/test ==> is a file
```